# siteurl change in wordpress ( changed in DB), but links still pointing to prior url

Tags: mysql, wordpress, debian, mariasql

I have a Wordpress installation for a client, and she's changed her domain name.
Because the former domain reg lapsed, I can no longer access any part of the site from its former domain, so I changed the vhost, to a subdomain of one of my domains to access it for now, but can only get its homepage, all the menu links are going to some spammy advertisement now parked on her former domain.
So I went into Maria DB and updated siteurl in the wp_options tableto the new subdomain, but nothing has changed, still being linked to the spammy parked ads from any of the links on the site's home page, even site.tld/wp-admin.php and site.tld/wp-login.php.
Is there, since I can't access the online/gui admin stuff, somewhere else in the DB where I can or need to change something to update ALL internal links to function on the new domain? The WP hasn't been updated since before the domain lapsed several months ago (client doesn't pay, I don't update domain reg...
Any and all assistance appreciated in advance.
Thanks,
Oh...I'm using MariaDB on Debian Jessie...or wait, the server is still running wheezy.

Comment: couldn't find anything seemingly relevant in wp-config.php

Comment: Did you change the domain dns ? If you did it, they maybe not propagated yet. You can try to force by accessing an admin page like /wp-admin/edit.php.

Comment: Re: DNS - I only added an A record for the subdomain, but ping already shows DNS pointing it to my server.

Answer (score 1):

You should also update the `home` option on the wp_options table to match the new domain, not only `siteurl`

Comment: This appears to have resolved the issue. :-) Thanks, Cristiano!

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help. This is the bare minimum necessary for you site to work again, but you should update at least the `guid` as Yahya H Hussein suggests. This is mainly important if you use WordPress feeds

Comment: spoke too soon, that got me to some pages, but others, no, nor blog posts, those are still getting redirected, but not to the spammy ads, at least!, just to the toplevel domain on my server, of which the new url is a a subdomain which I can't figure out, because I have other sites on subs of the same domain that function fine and I can't find any significant difference in the vhosts, or anything thatt I can identify that would cause the site to be re-routed to the toplevel... I'm stumped, but, at least the problem has changed, there's that.

Comment: Wait, it stopped working...I dunno why, I did  a2dissite,  and a2ensite $site, and reloaded apache2, and now the subdomain isn't being routed to the proper directory at all...perhaps it's time for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

if you have moved your wordpress website to a new domain what you have to do is to run these queries one by one in your database

```
update `wp_posts` set post_content = replace(post_content,'http://oldurl','http://newurl');
update `wp_posts` set guid = replace(guid ,'http://oldurl','http://newurl')
update `wp_options` set option_value = replace(option_value,'http://oldurl','http://newurl')
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to help when I can't even get the site's home to load now...

Comment: this is because urls are wrong in your DB, just do it, I have moved two many wordpress websites already, and this worked for all of them

Comment: @tonybaldwin you should give this a try. My answer is enough to just get the site working again unless you're using a multisite installation, but updates to guid (to fix feeds) and post_content (also post_excerpt and any meta data that might contain text with links or images) are necessary to fully fix the WordPress installation.

Comment: @tonybaldwin there is also the possibility that some data on postmeta table is serialized, so a simple SQL substitution won't work. You will need a script for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the wp-cli. Go to your WP root folder in your terminal and run the following command:

```sh
wp search-replace "old-domain.tld" "new-domain.tld"
```

If it's a multisite installation, use the flag `--network`

This should replace all the existing urls in your database.

You can also add the flag `--dry-run` to see a report about what's happening without saving changes to your database.

For more info:
https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Don't forget to check your `wp-config.php`